# How do you use Jimp to resize an image if needed

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, image-manipulation, jimp

I'm trying to use [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) to convert an image to JPG and keep a maximum size e.g. 1920x1920 keeping the original aspect ratio

However, some of my input files are smaller than that size.

I am thinking it is image.scaleToFit(1920, 1920, Jimp.AUTO) but make it so that it doesn't not resize if it is smaller.

I'm using Jimp because of Cordova, I need a pure JS solution as there is no plugin I found for Cordova that would do this transformation.